# aligning customized bootstrap Tool tip balloon with just outline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

in my project I have overridden Bootstrap styles in order to make custom tooltip balloon.

my css goes like this

```css
/*overriding bootstrap*/
.tooltip-inner {
    border: 1px solid #0ad;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px Arial;
    color: #494949;
    line-height: 18px;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.tooltip-arrow,
.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-width:7px!important;
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
 content: "";
}
.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow,.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-bottom-width:0!important;
    border-top-color: #0ad;
    bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-top-color: #fff;
 bottom: 1.5px;
}
.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow,.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-left-width:0!important;
    border-right-color: #0ad;
    left: -2px;
    margin-top: -7px;
 top:22px;/*overriding*/
}
.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-right-color: #fff;
 left: 1.5px;
 top:0;
}
.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow,.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-right-width:0!important;
    border-left-color: #0ad;
    right: -2px;
    margin-top: -7px;
 top:22px;/*overriding*/
}
.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-left-color: #fff;
 right: 1.5px; 
 top:0;
}
.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow,.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-top-width:0!important;
    border-bottom-color: #0ad;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow:after {
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 top: 1.5px;
}
```

My tooltip balloon:[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh0dU.png)

since the arrows are not in the middle I'm having a hard time to align the arrows with the (i) symbol because the height of the balloon changes with length of the text content.
can anyone help me with this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please, provide a demo(e.g. Jsfiddle)

Comment: sorry guys, couldnt demo this one, need to put alll the Bootstrap js :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, I found a fix.

```js
$(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
@import"http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
 
.lw {
    font-size: 60px;
}
.image {
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
}
/*overriding bootstrap*/
 .tooltip {
    box-shadow: none;
    z-index: 6000;
}
.tooltip.left, .tooltip.right {
  /*this makes the deference*/
    margin-top: -80px;
    top: 50%!important;
}
.tooltip.top, .tooltip.bottom {
    margin-left: 0px;/*just incase*/
}
.tooltip.top {
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.tooltip.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 0
}
.tooltip.left {
    margin-left: -15px;
    padding-left: 0
}
.tooltip.right {
    padding-right: 0
}
.tooltip-inner {
    border: 1px solid #0ad;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px Arial;
    color: #494949;
    line-height: 18px;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    width: 200px
}
.left>.tooltip-inner, .right>.tooltip-inner {
    text-align: left;
}
.tooltip-arrow, .tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-width:7px!important;
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    content:"";
}
.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow, .tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-bottom-width:0!important;
    border-top-color: #0ad;
    bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-top-color: #fff;
    bottom: 1.5px;
}
.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow, .tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-left-width:0!important;
    border-right-color: #0ad;
    left: -2px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    top:22px;
    /*offset*/
}
.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-right-color: #fff;
    left: 1.5px;
    top:0;
}
.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow, .tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-right-width:0!important;
    border-left-color: #0ad;
    right: -2px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    top:22px;
    /*offset*/
}
.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
    right: 1.5px;
    top:0;
}
.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow, .tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-top-width:0!important;
    border-bottom-color: #0ad;
    top: -2px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    top: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><div> 
<span data-original-title="Information about internet contract length" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" class="image"><a href="#">Tooltip</a></span>
  </div>
 

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
<p><code>.toolbar-right</code> <a href="#" class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip="I’m the tooltip text.">Tooltip</a></p>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/k7tb64wx/)

Or

```
<body>  <br /> <br /> <br /><br />


<p align="center">Hi, <a href="#" bubbletooltip="Hi I am a bubble tooltip">This is a demo </a></p>

</body>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/dhLa4wsa/)

**OR**

```
<a class="tooltips" href="#">CSS Tooltips
<span>Tooltip</span></a>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/fhg2f0qc/)

Comment: wait am creating another one answer sir @alirezasafian

Comment: Now You Can See My Demo Page Sir @alirezasafian

Comment: It is really good to try answering the question but none of them is answer of the question. For example [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/dhLa4wsa/)